Is asking for correction on questions written in Chinese on the comment considered too much?
I have checked several questions regarding whether it is fine to ask questions in Chinese, for example on the following:

Your input: Do we allow questions and answers written completely in Chinese?
Can I Answer Questions by Chinese
Asking questions completely in Chinese
To suggest that Chinese SE questions be written solely in English

While there is no clear consensus, at least the following seems supported, judged by the number of votes and how it works in other SE.

It is fine to ask questions in Chinese
The answerer is expected to post answers in the same language as the question

However, it is clear that almost all questions (or even all?) posted here are written in English. This is quite different from the other SE, for example Italian, French, Russian, and Spanish.
That said, as my Chinese is getting better, I would rather like to ask questions in Chinese. But my writing would likely have some mistakes, especially on grammar and vocabulary, even though the question is readable and understandable. 
In this case, aside from the body question, is asking for correcting my writing on the comment considered excessive (if not all)? Or is it fine to add it to the body of the question? Do people here mind reading practically the same content twice if I ask the part of my original questions as a separate post, to seek for checking and/or correction if I don't have enough confidence on the grammar and words?
Except the yes/no answer, any other suggestions are welcomed. 

Corrections to questions would be normally posted on the comments, as it falls under the proper use of comments being for clarification of the question. Admittedly, this mechanism won’t provide an explanation for why the question was worded incorrectly.

Please also see Is it a problem if a learner asks/answers wholly in broken Chinese?.  I was in a similar situation (although I've subsequently asked questions wholly in Chinese).

Corrections are okay.
The only thing is questions:

can't be open ended
need focus

You're better to ask a specific question about a certain type of sentence structure or a question on a certain topic rather than a "hey can you correct this for me"-type question.

I agree with your second point. What do you mean by “can’t be open ended”?

@Blaszard it just means that questions need to have a definite answer. That’s the reason we have a close vote for “opinion based.” It seems like correction based questions would easily become open-ended. A better option might be for you to invite users to edit your question(s), that way you could see what corrections were made and it wouldn’t interfere with the whole Q&A part of the site.

你想用什么语言提问或者回答都可以，不用顾虑太多。
You can ask or answer questions in whichever language you want, don't overthink.
我猜，这里会有人乐于纠正你书写方面的错误。如果你要求这样做的话。
I guess there might be some certain people who are glad to correct your writing.If you request to do so.
顺带一提，我是中文普通话母语者。
By the way, I am a Mandarin native Chinese speaker.
